# I want to interact with my View(Activity) from ViewModel. Using View.VISIBLE from ViewModel

Tags: java, android, mvvm

I want to hide and show my views from code. One option is to use `View.VISIBLE` from my ViewModel but that will impact the testing of the code in ViewModel.

I have read that it's not good practice to use Android specific things from ViewModel.

Either I can make an **interface** and interact with the view, but that will have a reference to the view. Will that be a good approach? I am currently **not** using **ViewModel Lifecycle Component** and extending my class with `BaseObservable`.

Eg.

I have

```
    @Bindable
    public int getButtonsVisibility() {
     //return visibility 
    }
```

and

```
 public void setButtonsVisibility(int buttonsVisibility) {
        this.buttonsVisibility = buttonsVisibility;
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.buttonsVisibility);
    }
```

Now If I want to call `setButtonsVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` from my viewModel, what will be a good approach?

Comment: You can use `LiveData` to update view from `ViewModel`

Answer (score 0):

I follow this approach to manage visibility ..

```
<data>
    <import type="android.view.View"/>
    <variable
        name="visible"
        type="java.lang.Boolean"/>
</data>

<View android:visibility="@{visible ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE}"/>
```